# Enable wireless is missing

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

I have newly installed Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but can't connect to WIFI. It is dual booted with Windows 8, and in windows I can connect to WIFI. Enable or Disable wireless option is absolutely missing in Linux. How can I reactivate wireless? Thanks in advance! My script is attached in the link below.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23083026/

Comment: In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, change `managed=false` to `managed=true` and do `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did it, but no result.

Comment: Would you please try: `sudo modprobe -r rt3290sta` and next: `sudo modprobe rt2800pci` and then post a new wireless_script?

Comment: I have installed rt3290 wireless driver and that solved my problem. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its probably a driver issue. From the txt info your wifi hardware is Ralink rt3290. You need to download and compile the right driver for your hardware to work.

1. Download the driver
   [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/pu4rejmmft8z9yr/RT3290_u16_v1.tar.gz).
2. Extract the archive.
3. Open a terminal and go to the extracted folder using.

> cd /path/to/the/extracted/folder

4. Become root

> ```
> sudo -i
> ```

5. Run the command as follows.

> ```
> ./Run.sh
> ```

That's it. This will install the driver and you need to reboot your system after installation of driver is completed.

Comment: Installed successfully and problem is solved! Thank you so much!